# general technique in Windows to install software once and replicate the configuration?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, installation

I would like, in general, to be able to install software on windows into a directory or directories, zip up the files that have been created, and create a script that sets the registry appropriately.

Is there any utility that does that?  For that matter, once you can do one, you can presumably do any number of packages in a single zip file with a single install script.

If this is not doable, can I specifically do it for packages such as cygwin which take a huge amount of time to install because of the interactive nature of specifying which packages to install, and then installing them one by one?

Comment: I would love if there was an easy way to do this... I frequently have to load systems with a few standard programs, with standard settings. Unfortunately slipstreaming seems like the only option if the systems have varying components.

Answer (score 1):

http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php has a complete set of instructions for various kinds of installers. Keyboard and Mouse Macro scripters like AutoIt or AutoHotKey can also work by automating the mouseclick and button presses for you.

Comment: This isn't really a good solution, but it is better than nothing I guess. Thanks....